# How to show this fact about determinants?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

My professor in mechanics class used the following theorem.

Theorem: If $\vec{a}, \vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ are three linearly independent vector, then:

$$ \det (A) = \frac{(A \vec{a}, A \vec{b}, A \vec{c})}{(\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c})} $$

Now, I assume, as I'm not even entirely sure about this, that notation $(\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c})$ represents scalar triple product. Now, he said that we should already know that and that if we don't, we can try to prove it ourselves, that it is a trivial fact. I can't figure out what to do, however. I guess you could do it by rewriting it in coordinates and that computing all the operations, but that would be like hell. There must be an elegant way to show it! I would appreciate it a lot, if someone can show me how it's done.

Comment: Your professor used in class a notation, you are not sure what it means and you did not ask him? If he had started to talk in Sanskrit at some point, would you have stopped to tell him that you were not understanding what he was saying?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez how do you know that the OP is not fluent in Sanscrit?

Comment: If I told you I'd have to kill you later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed true, provided $(a, b, c) \neq 0$, and it can be shown without too much hassle.

First, recall that
$$(a, b, c) = \det\left(\begin{array}{c}a\\\hline b\\ \hline c\end{array}\right),$$
i.e. the determinant of the matrix whose rows are the vectors $a, b, c$. This can be seen using the standard mnemonic for the cross product, and the cofactor definition of the determinant:
\begin{align*}
(a, b, c) &= a \cdot (b \times c) \\
&= a \cdot \begin{vmatrix} i & j & k \\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \end{vmatrix} \\
&= a \cdot \left( \begin{vmatrix} b_2 & b_3 \\ c_2 & c_3 \end{vmatrix}i - \begin{vmatrix} b_1 & b_3 \\ c_1 & c_3 \end{vmatrix}j + \begin{vmatrix} b_1 & b_2 \\ c_1 & c_2 \end{vmatrix}k \right) \\
&= \begin{vmatrix} b_2 & b_3 \\ c_2 & c_3 \end{vmatrix}a_1 - \begin{vmatrix} b_1 & b_3 \\ c_1 & c_3 \end{vmatrix}a_2 + \begin{vmatrix} b_1 & b_2 \\ c_1 & c_2 \end{vmatrix}a_3 \\
&= \begin{vmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \end{vmatrix}.
\end{align*}
Next, we note that, if we let
$$B = \left(\begin{array}{c}a\\\hline b\\ \hline c\end{array}\right)^\top = \left(\begin{array}{c|c|c}&&\\a&b&c\\&&\end{array}\right),$$
i.e. the matrix with $a, b, c$ as columns, then $\det(B) = \det(B^\top) = (a, b, c)$. We can then use the following fact about matrix multiplication (which is worth remembering, but really needs to be proven by definition):
$$AB = A\left(\begin{array}{c|c|c}&&\\a&b&c\\&&\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c|c|c}&&\\Aa&Ab&Ac\\&&\end{array}\right).$$
That is, multiplying a matrix $A$ on the right is the same as multiplying each individual column by $A$. So, putting it together, we get
$$(Aa, Ab, Ac) = \det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B) = \det(A)(a, b, c),$$
which leads immediately to the formula.